# How can I replace a Ubuntu partition with a Fedora Workstation 25 one?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, windows, dual-boot

I am running a dual boot machine with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04. I want to leave the Windows partition as is, and completely replace Ubuntu with Fedora Workstation 25. I have created a USB to boot Fedora from and started working through the "install to hard drive process". That part is all fine.

I am a bit lost when I get to the part where I am meant to select the mounts for the partition. There are lots of different schemes and so on, and one which says something like "automatically select partitioning scheme", but I'm worried this will delete part of the Windows partition to make space, or leave Ubuntu on there, or something.

**What is the simplest way for me to replace Ubuntu with Fedora, while leaving Windows untouched?** I am a complete non-expert, and don't understand enough to follow the online tutorials I have seem (which tend to assume you have Windows installed and want to add a second OS, rather than replace the second OS with a third one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the "select installation destination" screen in the installer:

[image]

Pick the drive you want, and then check "I would like to make additional space available". After doing that, press "Done" in the upper left. This will bring up a dialog which will let you select the Ubuntu partition for removal. Select everything but Windows to delete (leaving the Windows partitions as "Preserve") and press the "Reclaim Space" button. (Windows partitions may show up as `ntfs`.)

Note that in any case, **no changes to the disk will be made until you hit "Begin Installation"**, so it is **safe to play around here**. (But that said, please do back up your data before starting the install, because disasters do happen.)

This will work with either the "Automatically configure partitioning" option (in which case the installer will use the space you've freed to create a new default partition scheme), or "I will configure partitioning" (which will, of course, let you do that).